# Koch's Snowflake using Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, fractals

I'm currently doing a project where I need to create Koch's Snowflake. I decided to use turtle for this assignment. The user can enter an "order" which determineres the amount of sides the triangle has. I'm having a problem where from a higher order like "6" the lines become so blurred on the triangle so I can't even see if its working. Is there a way to fix this? one solution I had would be if the user could zoom in they might be able the details more clearly.

Code :

```
import turtle
from turtle import \*
from turtle import Screen

t = turtle.Turtle()

turtle.tracer(False)

screen = Screen()

def draw_kochs(length, n):
   if (n == 0):
      t.forward(length)
   else:
      n = n - 1
      length = length / 3
      draw_kochs(length, n)
      t.right(60)
      draw_kochs(length, n)
      t.left(120)
      draw_kochs(length, n)
      t.right(60)
      draw_kochs(length, n)

t.penup()
t.setposition(0, 0)
t.pendown()
t.speed(10)
order = screen.textinput("Order Number", "Please Enter Order Number")
order = int(order)
order = order - 1
for x in range(3):
draw_kochs(200, order)
t.left(120)

input()
```

I tried to find others answers online but found very little support for turtle.

Answer (score 0):

If it is blurred you should increase the size of the area. — Not by zooming in but by setting the count of pixels with `turtle.screensize()`:

```
import turtle

# Get the current value (in Pixels)
print(turtle.screensize())

=> (300,300)

# Set a higher value:
turtle.screensize(canvwidth=600, canvheight=600, bg="white")
```

But note that more Pixels to calculate (an area goes by x²) can slow down the execution speed.

##### Addendum:

Surely it is no use to let the turtle walk the same small structure on a larger area. It should be obvious that the turtle should use the maximum of the available area to fulfill its task.

As a result the drawn structure covers more calculated pixels. So displaying this larger will not or less be blurred as more information (pixels) are avaliable to represent the structure.

Finally by doing this we've increased the "dpi" (Dots Per Inch) of the turtle's drawing.

=> That's been your question here.

Comment: I don't see how this would work.  `screensize()`increases the number of pixels but not their density, so small detail would remain small, there'd just be more space to draw more small details.  Perhaps you could flesh this out with example code.

Comment: I've updated my answer. But its is not useful to expect that other people recalculate your study work. — To become a manager to be able to outsource the work you will hopefully have success, but this is not now.  — I think that's fair play ...

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky in turtle as two functions that we'd want to implement zooming, `setworldcoordinates()` and `screensize()` don't play nicely together.  Below is a simplified example using only `setworldcoordinates()`.  Once the fractal is drawn, click on the window to keep enlarging a corner of it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500

def draw_kochs(length, n):
    if n == 0:
        turtle.forward(length)
    else:
        n -= 1
        length /= 3

        draw_kochs(length, n)
        turtle.right(60)
        draw_kochs(length, n)
        turtle.left(120)
        draw_kochs(length, n)
        turtle.right(60)
        draw_kochs(length, n)

adjust = 2

def zoom(x, y):
    global adjust

    adjust += 1
    screen.setworldcoordinates(-WIDTH/adjust, -HEIGHT/adjust, WIDTH/adjust, HEIGHT/adjust)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

order = screen.numinput("Order Number", "Please Enter Order Number:", minval=1, maxval=10)

screen.setworldcoordinates(-WIDTH/adjust, -HEIGHT/adjust, WIDTH/adjust, HEIGHT/adjust)  # initial null change
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

for _ in range(3):
    draw_kochs(200 * order, order)
    turtle.left(120)

screen.update()
screen.onclick(zoom)
screen.mainloop()
```

To move around in an enlarged fractal, we'd want `screensize()`, which again doesn't play well with `setworldcoordinates()`.  To get around this, we have to implement our own scalable coordinate functionality, toss `setworldcoordinates()` and use `screensize()` to create a large backing image store to scroll around in.